# programmatically tack UIView to screen edge like you can in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, ipad

Is it possible to dynamically create a UIView and attach to a screen edge like you can with your views in Interface Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  Set it's origin and width in code, then the appropriate autoresizing masks.

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
v.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Whereas on the Mac, you heavily lean on IB, production quality apps on iOS tend to rely more heavily, if not completely, on code generated UI.

Comment: I completely disagree with your assertion that iOS apps rely more heavily on code-generated UI. I think it's merely a matter of preference, although I don't understand why anyone would want to manually manage a bunch of complicated layout logic. Honestly, I think it's a lack of understanding that prevents people from using IB.

Comment: I think it's lack of understanding that keeps people using IB :)  There are just too many things that you can only do in code, and to not have all of your logic in one place is madness.